# Python file opening with quote inside newline parameter

Tags: python

I have a tsv file with content like:

```
'"1"\t"2"\t"3"\t"4"\n'
'"5"\t"6\n7"\t"8"\t"9"\n'
```

I want to be able to ignore \n symbols inside double quotes, but file's readline() method read it like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6
7 8 9
```

What I want is:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6\n7 8 9
```

I tried to pass it to the newline parameter:

```
f = open('file.tsv', newline = '"\n')
f = open('file.tsv', newline = '\"\n')
```

But I get

```
ValueError: illegal newline value: "
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Readline method doesn't parce tsv-like strings, just reads the content as it is. Python provides CSV package to read such files:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Read more abuot this package [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

BTW, your trick with newline argument throws an error because it can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`.

Note that newline only applies to text mode.

**UPDATE**:

See the example with topicstarter's data below:

```
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO("""'"1"\t"2"\t"3"\t"4"'
'"5"\t"6\n7"\t"8"\t"9"'""")
reader =csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['\'"1"', '2', '3', "4'"]
['\'"5"', '6\n7', '8', "9'"]
```

So it works as expected - splitting cannot be performed right when you open the file, `csv.reader` working with file object, not with the lines.

Comment: csv module doesn't deal with this. As I see splitting into the lines happening on the point where I open the file. csv only further parsing lines, which open object gave to it. Your method will still split it into 3 lines.

Comment: @Sht0p0r, see the example with your data in the updated answer. Splitting into the lines happens in `csv.reader` - `open` just creates file object. I use StringIO in the example, but just tested it with file - still works fine